# How to transform an array to a list of args for method invocation in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, variadic-functions

I have been puzzled by this problem for two days. I have a list of testN methods in the Class Test, and i will add more test* methods for this class. The sample code is shown below

```
public class Test {

    public void test1(String a, int b, boolean c){
        System.out.println("a="+a+"  "+b+ " c="+c);
    }

    public void test3(Test test){
        System.out.println(test.toString());
    }


    public void run(Object... objs){
        //First way...
        if(objs.length>=3){
            test1((String)objs[0], (int)objs[1], (boolean)objs[2]);
        }else if(objs.length <3 ){
            test3((Test)objs[0]);
        }
        //Second way? 
        MethodType type1 = MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class, int.class, boolean.class);
        if(objs.length>=3){


//How to tranform first 3 elements of objs to a list (String, int, boolean) 
            Object[] t = Arrays.copyOfRange(objs, 0, type1.parameterCount());
            test1(???);

        }

        MethodType type3 = MethodType.methodType(void.class, Test.class);
        if(objs.length < 3 ){


        }       

    }
    public  static void main(String[] args){
        Test test = new Test();
        test.run("String", 3, false, 5,7);
        test.run(test,1);
    }
}
```

the method `run(Object... objs)` is the main entry for this class, and it accepts a list of var args. Inside of method `run`, it invokes different test* method according to the objs' length (objs is recognized as array).

The problem for me is that how can i pass the `Object[] t` in the second way as a list of var args for method `test1`? The first way is handle-write which is not practical when more `test*` methods are added. The `Object[] t` is array and it is one object while `test1` requires three parameters. I am seeking a way that can transform an array into a list of args for method invocation.

Comment: I tried this before but compilation fails. Because asList return List<Object> which does not match the `test1`'s parameter. This is the same as i pass the `Object[] t` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use reflection. First, get your Test.class — that's easy, it's just `Test.class`. Next, get your method, this can be done either by knowing the types from your arguments (via `.getClass()` on each argument and the `.getMethod(…)` method of `Class` or by searching the array returned by `getMethods()`. Both will give you a `Method` object to work with. Finally, you can call the method with `method.invoke(this, objs);`.

Edit: Regarding your comment, there is no *List* of parameters. At least not as in `java.util.List`. The JVM indeed places the parameters on the stack (and is free to do so in any conceivable way; heck even the stack will in many cases be optimized away into registers).

So the problem is, you'd need to a) know the VM type of the object (which could be any of int, long, float, double, or ref) and b) the position of the object. Then you could do something similar by creating a synthetic bytecode sequence (note that while this would yield valid JVM bytecode, there is no valid Java code that does this unless you count custom class loaders). Otherwise, no, there is no way in Java to create an 'argument list'.

Comment: This is another kind of way, similar to new MethodHandle in Java, to invoke with Object[]. It avoids the problem i encountered. Yet, i am still waiting whether there is some easy way to convert an object[] to a list of parameters..

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Now i am trying using *load, *store bytecode instructon to generate new bytecode which places elements of Object[] at JVM stack. Hope this work.